# "For someone" vs "for whom"

Tags: grammar

When to use the former and when to use the latter? Example:

> We believe in *seeking*, and don't seek for someone to believe.
>
> We believe in *seeking*, and don't seek for whom to believe.

Which one is the correct version?

Comment: Why do you think it might or might not be grammatical? Please explain why you are asking here. Because this site is not a substitute for having a friend to practice your English with.

Comment: @curiousdannii I edited the question.

Comment: I think you still need to give us some more information. Or maybe you can ask this question in the ELL chat, where you can have a chance to have a conversation about it and make your question more clear and complete: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners

Answer (score 1):

Those sentences have completely different meanings, and they are both marginally grammatical; "marginal" in the sense that, when parsed, they make sense but are not in contemporary idiom. We must seek out a context where they make sense.

Let's eliminate the part of the sentence which has no bearing on the grammar, "in seeking, and".  (Why has *seeking* been placed in italics?)

> We don't seek for someone to believe.
>
> We don't seek for whom to believe.

There are two verbs we should know about, *believe*, and *believe in*.

**Do you *believe in* ghosts?**  Do you think ghosts actually exist?

**Do you *believe* that politician?**  Or is he lying to save his own ass?

*Believe* can be used transitively (that is, we believe *someone* or *something*) but it can also be used absolutely, with an unstated object:

**I believe!**

In such absolute uses, only the context gives us the information we would need in order to know what it is that the speaker believes.  With no context, the statement is grammatical but the meaning cannot be determined.

**I believe!**
--*What do you believe?  I've only just arrived and must have missed part of the conversation.*

Let's go back to your first sentence.

> We don't seek for someone to believe.

The object complement of "seek for" is "someone to believe", and *believe* has no object, so it must be an absolute use. This sentence could be paraphrased:

*Our goal is not to cause someone else to place their trust in something.*

We can change the meaning dramatically if we add the word "in":

**We don't seek for someone to believe in.**

*Our goal is not to find someone in whom we can place our trust.*

Now let's look at the second sentence:

> We don't seek for whom to believe.

This sentence, if parsed "as is", is grammatical but somewhat archaic. It is not in *contemporary* English idiom. To me it sounds like something that could have been said during the British Raj in India. It could be paraphrased:

*It is not our goal to discover which person we should believe.*

P.S. *Seek* and *seek for* deserve their own separate question.

Comment: how about "We don't seek someone to believe"? Is that more common than, "We don't seek for someone to believe"?

Comment: *We don't seek someone to believe* would mean "We are not trying to find someone whom we can believe."  It cannot be compared, in terms of frequency, against "We don't seek for someone to believe" because they mean different things. It would have to be compared against "We don't seek for someone to believe *in*".  "Seek for" is complicating your sentence.  "Seek" and "seek for" demand different object complements.